# ERPnext :custom script on sales invoice

Tags: erpnext

I need to change amount calculation for each item  in sales invoice to be:

`amount = rate * qty * custom_field`

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
frappe.ui.form.on("Sales Invoice Item", "custom_field", (frm, cdt, cdn) => {
  var d = locals[cdt][cdn];
  frappe.model.set_value("amount", d.qty*d.custom_field*d.rate) ;
});
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: yes @JeansK.Real after following this tutorial :https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/tutorial I have duplicated sales invoice and sales invoive item doctypes and created custom scripts for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set value should be used like

```
frappe.model.set_value(DOC_TYPE, DOC_NAME, FIELD_NAME, NEW_VALUE);
```

So, in your case

```
frappe.model.set_value("Sales Invoice Item", cdn, "amount", d.qty*d.custom_field*d.rate);
```

Or

```
frappe.model.set_value(cdt, cdn, "amount", d.qty*d.custom_field*d.rate);
```